# WPF Richtextbox unable to get focus, use scrollbars etc

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Issue: I am unable to select the Richtextbox 'rtbx_COMMENTS' either using keyboard or mouse. Having tried and retried various properties and values for this control I am at a loss as to why this is not selectable

The controls useage is read only but it needs to be selectable so it can be vertically scrolled

I have manually added the properties  IsEnabled="True" and  Focusable ="True" into the XAML definition for the control as a belts and braces effort to try and get this control selectable. I even set the stackpanel as focusable wondering if the richtextbox was inheriting properties from it

In the codebehind, I use ONLY the follow to manipulate this control, clearing the control, appending text etc

```
        rtbx_COMMENTS.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        rtbx_COMMENTS.AppendText(_x.COMMENT);
```

where _x.COMMENT refers to a string, example being

***"Select If : Gas Issue affecting every burner\r Smell of gas when appliance not in use"***

and the XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spnl_COMMENTS" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="780" Focusable="True">
    <Label x:Name="lbl_COMMENTS" Content="COMMENTS" Margin="5,1,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF45CDDA" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFABA63A" Width="115" TabIndex="-1" Height="145"/>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbx_COMMENTS" IsEnabled="True"  Focusable ="True" BorderBrush="#FF45CDDA" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,5,0" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFE48989" IsReadOnly="False" FontSize="16" MinWidth="655" Width="655" Height="145" TabIndex="19" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MinHeight="145" IsDocumentEnabled="True" Cursor="Arrow" UseLayoutRounding="False" AllowDrop="False" IsTabStop="True" >
    </RichTextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IsHitTestVisible="False"`  property in XAML, causes the problem of not selecting the text in rich text box.